# CSS Adjust div width to text content width up to X pixels

Tags: css

I'm looking for something such as:

```
width: (200px or content width)
```

Any ideas?

**[EDIT]** Added a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9fhtsgfd/

Comment: sounds like some sort of conditional is needed? something like: http://www.conditional-css.com/usage (right hand side?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` is `display: block` by default, meaning it will take up **full width**. If you want it to only take up the space of its content you can try `inline-block` instead.

Then, if you only want the `<div>` to stretch **up to** X pixels, you can use `max-width`.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: blue; /* for illustration only */
}
```

```html
<div>short content</div>
<div>longer content here longer content here longer content here longer content here longer content here longer content here longer content here </div>
```

As you can tell, this also puts the divs next to eachother.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Sounds like you are looking for the css property min-width</s>

```
min-width:200px;
width:auto;
```

Sorry maybe i read the question wrong.

```
max-width:200px;
display:inline-block; //xec is correct inline-block instead of display block lets it adjust from 0-max-width. I was missing that piece until he posted his answer. His is correct.
```

This will take text and wrap it at 200px wide but the container will expand from 0 px up to 200px. If it is not behaving in this way then you likely have other css causing problems.

Comment: nope. If the content is less than 200px I want the width to be the content width, not 200px.

Comment: then use `max-width` instead.

Comment: It would be more like `max-width: 200; width: auto;`. But in that case the content gets wrapped before reaching 200px. I don't know why...

Comment: Yes then i would recommend just omitting the width tag in general. Without seeing all of your html/css then i can't really give you a perfect solution. Just guesses of what you want.

Comment: `max-width: 200px` + `width: auto` does not seem to work in any case, not only mine. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/9fhtsgfd/ (Chrome still renders a 800px width div in both cases in that example)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hatterismad/9fhtsgfd/2/
Using display:inline-block and max-width as suggested by xec